# MouseMoveEvent stops being called

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2, qcustomplot

I'm using *QCustomPlot* (plot_ object) on *QQuickPaintedItem* (SinePlot class) so I can use it in QML. In *mousePressEvent* I collect initial point and in *mouseMoveEvent* I'm making calculations to add new points and updating cursor point:

```
void SinePlot::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    prevPoint_ = event->globalPos();
}

void SinePlot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QPointF tmp = event->globalPos();
    qreal prop = (prevPoint_.x() - tmp.x()) / width();
    if(prop > 0)
    {
        data_->shiftLeft(prop);
    } else {
        data_->shiftRight(prop);
    }
    plot_->xAxis->setRange(data_->minX, data_->maxX);
    ...
    prevPoint_ = tmp;
    update();
}
```

I have also trying to use *pos()* and *localPos()* but it does not make any difference, here is what I got:

[image]

As you can see *mouseMoveEvent* stops being called after some time(before releasing) and moving cursor does not call it.

Here is minimal reproducible example:

```
#ifndef SINEPLOT_H
#define SINEPLOT_H

#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QDebug>

class SinePlot : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SinePlot(QQuickItem* parent=nullptr)
    {
            setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
            plot_ = new QCustomPlot();
            plot_->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag);
            plot_->addGraph();
    }
    virtual ~SinePlot()
    {
        delete plot_;
    }
    void paint(QPainter* painter)
    {
        QPicture picture;
        QCPPainter qcpPainter;
        qcpPainter.begin(&picture);
        plot_->toPainter(&qcpPainter, width(), height());
        qcpPainter.end();
        picture.play(painter);
    };

protected:    
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {};
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse move";
    };


private:
    QCustomPlot* plot_;
};

#endif
```

In my case I got *"mouse move"* ~10 times.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Did this happens if you use it in cpp ? I asked this because I want to know this happens just because you use it in qml or not.

Comment: And as @eyllanesc says , please edit your question and put example that we could run and test it , maybe your problem wasn't related to this part of code.

Comment: I would add a few `qDebug() << ...` calls into your code so that you can see and check whether the values of variable in the event handler are what you expect. Btw. calling `shiftRight(prop)` with negative value of `prop`... doesn't it actually shift left? Are you sure that you supply correct values to these `shiftLeft()` and `shiftRight()` functions? Are they really expected to be relative to the width of the widget? It does not seem OK to me. I would expect them to be relative to the displayed range, but I may be wrong.

Comment: And another potential issue: Are you sure that shifting data makes sense at all? Why don't you just change the range of the axis?

Comment: @V.K., thanks for idea with shifting the range, that's actually would be smart two make sine of two periods and just shift range, I will think about it!
For the first part about *prop*,  *shiftLeft()* and *shiftRight()*; the current problem has nothing to do with it, as far as I can judge

Comment: @JuicyKitty Are you sure that the error depends on QCustomPlot? The MRE shows that you only use it to draw and if you remove it I presume the problem will persist. On the other hand, that code is not an MRE, it does not show how you use that class (for example the .qml code).

Comment: @eyllanesc, damn, seems problem really comes out of qml, didn't expect that it might be the reason, thanks a lot! I will dive bit more to figure out why that happens

Comment: @JuicyKitty try add `event->accept();` in mousePressEvent.

Comment: It seams that qml's `ScrollView` disturbs `mouseMoveEvent` call, since if I substitute `ScrollView` with `Pane` all works well, just can't scroll widgets